# How to select random rows from a matrix in python scratch without any numpy library

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, genetic-algorithm, fitness

Hi i am trying to inplememt Genetic algorithm rollete wheel selection mechanism. I have done fitness and also the corresponding fitness probability.
I need a code to randomly select rows from initial generated matrix.but only using scratch python bc i am not using any libary such as numpy or jupyter

Same like this one but without numpy

[Select two random rows from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835914/select-two-random-rows-from-numpy-array)

Thank you

Comment: Please include code snippets of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to select rows from matrix

Comment: Same like this one but without numpy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835914/select-two-random-rows-from-numpy-array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835914/select-two-random-rows-from-numpy-array

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.sample()`:

```py
import random  # for random.sample

# This is an example matrix
A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]


num_random_rows_desired = 2
a = random.sample(A, num_random_rows_desired)
print(a)
```

Comment: it gives just one row in output randomly every time I want the row same as in this array A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]] and also the rows which have smaller in some will be omitted like 1+2+3 = 6 it will be omitted 3 new rows will be generated randomly from remaining two rows of array A

Comment: Updated answer.